# Relation between Struts-config.xml and web.xml(deployment desc.)

Tags: struts

A new bie to struts. What is the life-cycle followed and what is the relation between web.xml file and the struts-config.xml file?   
 
Can you provide links?

Answer (score 2):

http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/faqs/works.html
This explains everything.....

Comment: Since you are learning, learn Struts2, not Struts1. It's easier, more powerful and *not dead*.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml is used for making connection between web container & web application and read by container itself when we start it. 
struts-config.xml used for making connection between view & controller and initialized by using init() method.